# Isn't it possible to grant access to IAM user by just clicking some buttons?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created `S3` bucket and have created `IAM` user in `AWS`.

Now I want to grant access for this user to this bucket.

My found examples of doing this in internet are all contains of edition some JSON texts and are all don't work for me with some error messages.

Is this true, that the only way to grant access for `IAM` user is by editing `JSON` text? Why isn't it possible to just add permissions in web interface by clicking something on page?

Where can I read the documentation of that JSON code I need to write a policy?

Comment: See the IAM policy visual editor, documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_create.html#access_policies_create-visual-editor It is a fairly new feature of the IAM console.

Answer (score 0):

All policy documents are in Json. It is a good thing because it gives you granular control of what access you provide. If you do not want that just add a `new permission -> Attach existing policies directly -> AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess`

or full access whatever you want (This is also json but you don't have to worry about what's underneath).

In my opinion you should create your own policy with granular control and attach it to your user. You can use AWS policy generator for that -
https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html